# How would I normalize this un-normalized database table?

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I am programming a site which stores poker session data. A session is a period of time spent at a casino playing poker. A session contains information such as the date/time, the net profit/loss of the session, and the location where they played. However, the part I'm confused about is how to handle a session **type**. In poker there are two kinds of games: cash games and tournaments. Each have their own specific fields pertinent **only** to them. Here is an example table (I've removed the irrelevant fields):

```
+----+--------------+--------+--------+
| id | session type | stakes | buy-in |
+----+--------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | cash         | 1/3 NL | NULL   |
|  2 | cash         | 1/2 NL | NULL   |
|  3 | tournament   | NULL   | $20    |
+----+--------------+--------+--------+
```

As you can see, I do not need `buy-in` if the session type is cash. Similarly, if the session type is tournament, I do not need the `stakes` field.

How would I go about normalizing my table such that I do not have NULL fields? Performance-wise, will my application suffer if I'm normalizing this table just to make it so I do not have NULL values in my row?

Comment: leave one field with name rate/rank or something

Comment: I like Lashane's first answer, but if the only difference is one column and everything else is already written, I would just make sure session_type is an index and move on to something else. There won't be a huge performance gain by normalizing unless you have millions of rows

Comment: Your current table is normalized, it is an implementation of an "is-a" relation. Lashanes first solution is another way of implementing an "is-a" relation. `null` values in your implementation are perfectly fine (and allowed in normalization), and you will get them back when you do a `select * from sessions left join cash_sessions on... left join tournament_session on ...`, which is the standard query to do anything with your data. It will be slower (because of the join), but will save some storage (on hdd (less important) and in ram (a bit more important, though the join requires ram too)).

Comment: Normalization is done to relational tables. They do not contain SQL NULL. Even if you treat NULL as a normal value, you don't mean "normalize", you mean you want to record the same data as this table without using NULL. Guessing, your table holds rows where "session ID is of type SESSION TYPE and (its stakes are STAKES or STAKES IS NULL) and (its buy-in is BUY-IN or BUY-IN IS NULL)". So: How to represent the same data about your application situation that this does? Hint: What are some shorter/separate statements about your application situation you would like to record?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution:

**sessions:**

```
id_session (PK)
session_type (Integer/Enum)
```

**cash_sessions:**

```
id_session (FK)
stakes
```

**tournament_sessions:**

```
id_session (FK)
buy_in
```

So, separate table for every session type, thus you will be able to define different columns for different types, also have common columns in `sessions` table

Example data:

```
sessions
1 1
2 1
3 2

cash_sessions
1 1/3 NL
2 1/2 NL

tournament_sessions
3 $20
```

Another solution:

**sessions:**

```
id_session (PK)
session_type (Integer/Enum) <- basically useless field for this schema
```

**attributes:**

```
id_attr (PK)
name (String)
```

**session_attributes:**

```
id_session (FK)
id_attr(FK)
value (String)
```

so, instead of thinking in terms of "session type" you can change your business model to think about "session attributes", so, different sessions can have different sets of attributes assigned

Example data:

```
sessions
1 1
2 1
3 2

attributes
1 stakes
2 buy_in

session_attributes
1 1 1/3 NL
2 1 1/2 NL
3 2 $20
```